# Play 'this' parent video with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using HTML5 video player and custom controls button. 
Here is my HTML structure:

```
<video width="840" id="video">

                  <source src="{{box.video}}" type="video/mp4">

                  </video>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <button class="play" ><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

JS code:

```
 $(".play").click(function() {
              $(this).closest("video")[0].play();
            });
```

When I click play button, its getting undefined error. Whats the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: You're source's `src` is a little strange. Do you use Angularjs or Angular?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS

Comment: why do you need jQuery? whats wrong angular's ng-click?

Comment: Actually I don't know how can I do it with ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `video` is not a parent of the `.play` button which gets clicked. Given your HTML sample, you need to use `closest()` to get the `.controls` div, then `prev()` to get the video, like this:

```js
$(".play").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.controls').prev('video')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<video width="840" id="video">
  <source src="{{box.video}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="controls">
  <button class="play">
    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```